# Documenting a function that renders a JSON with Yard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yard

If I have a function that returns this:

```
render :json => @orders.as_json(include: [{:user => {only: :id}}], :only => [:id, :status_id])
```

I am documenting it like this:

```
 # @return [JSON] includes the id, the order status id and the id of the associated user
```

I am wondering if there is a better way of document how the returned JSON will look like.

Comment: Did you find a better way?

Answer (score -2):

So if you care about the documentation of you API I assume that you also care about testing so your API end points probably have test. I would suggest that you using [Rspec API Documentation](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation). If you are not currently using Rspec I would give [Apipie](https://github.com/Apipie/apipie-rails) a try. Both of these tools will help to insure that your API documentation is consistent and stays up to date.